# How to give a value to matching data from different dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, join, sum, string-matching

So I have two dataframe looking like that :

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = c("l", "b", "c", "i", "e", "h", "g"),
                  v2 = c("a", "c", "b", "f", "g", "n", "m"),
                  v3 = c("m", "h", "f", "c", "d", "j", "k"))

df2 <- data.frame(v1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"),
                  v2 = c(1,6,5,4,2,9,7,3,2,1,4,5,6,9))
```

And what I want is to associate the matching number of the letter of df2 to df1 and then add the sum of these values in a new column. The values does not repeat in the same row but can be find in a different row and different column. (for example the value "c")

I've found a way of doing it using `ifelse` like this :

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){

ifelse([i,] == "a", df1$total[i] <- df1$Total[i] + df2[1,2], df1$Total[i])

}
```

But with that way, I need to write a different `ifelse` statement for each values.

The result I want should be this :

```
v1    v2    v3    Total
l     a     c     11
b     c     h     14
c     b     f     20
i     f     c     16
e     g     d     13
h     n     j     15
g     m     k     17
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(v1 = c("l", "b", "c", "i", "e", "h", "g"),
                  v2 = c("a", "c", "b", "f", "g", "n", "m"),
                  v3 = c("m", "h", "f", "c", "d", "j", "k"))

df2 <- data.frame(v1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"),
                  v2 = c(1,6,5,4,2,9,7,3,2,1,4,5,6,9))

df1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(total = df2$v2[df2$v1 == v1] + df2$v2[df2$v1 == v2] + df2$v2[df2$v1 == v3]) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 7 × 4
#>   v1    v2    v3    total
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 l     a     m        12
#> 2 b     c     h        14
#> 3 c     b     f        20
#> 4 i     f     c        16
#> 5 e     g     d        13
#> 6 h     n     j        13
#> 7 g     m     k        17
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve your problem:

```
# way 1
df3$total = Reduce(`+`, lapply(df1, \(x,y) y[x], setNames(df2$v2, df2$v1)))

# or
library(kit)
df1$total = psum(lapply(df1, vswitch, df2$v1, df2$v2))

  v1 v2 v3 total
1  l  a  m    12
2  b  c  h    14
3  c  b  f    20
4  i  f  c    16
5  e  g  d    13
6  h  n  j    13
7  g  m  k    17
```

Answer (score 0):

With base R, we can use `apply` to match the values from all cells, then `rowSums` on the values.

```
df1$Total <- rowSums(apply(df1, c(1, 2), \(x) df2[df2$v1 == x, 2]))

  v1 v2 v3 Total
1  l  a  m    12
2  b  c  h    14
3  c  b  f    20
4  i  f  c    16
5  e  g  d    13
6  h  n  j    13
7  g  m  k    17
```

Comment: Why c(1, 2)? Shouldn't be c(1, 2, 3)? And what's "x"? The different values "a","b","c" etc...? Which would mean that I have to write a different line for each value?

Comment: Right, so if I understand good, apply(df1, c(1, 2) means apply the function to df1 entirely and then the function means for all the value of df1 (x) if df2$v1 = x take its number (2) and then sum everything with rowSums. But I get 'x' must be numeric error and I'm a bit confused

Comment: @CypEg Your understanding is correct. Make sure the v2 column from your actual dataset is numeric, you can use as.integer() if it’s not numeric. I.e. as.integer(df2[df2$v1 == x, 2])

Comment: My V2 column is numeric but get the 'x' must be numeric error and when I try with as.integer the code results with only NAs. But I will try the other solutions, I'm more familiar with dplyr, thanks for your help !